# Controlar Checkbox en angularJS

Tags: angularjs

Tengo un checkbox y quiero controlar su acción desde el controlador cuando sea `false` o `true`.

aquí les dejo el **Html**:

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="checkstate" aria-label="Checkbox 1" ng-true-value="'prioritario'" ng-false-value="'Normal'">
     {{checknull}}
</md-checkbox>
```

"El fín es que el controlador sea quien controle la acción."

Al logearme recibo un JSON : *id_servicio:"38,39"* , los separo con un split y los almaceno en *localStorage* quedando en :

- *LoginData.getData().id_servicio.split(",")[0]* ,
- *LoginData.getData().id_servicio.split(",")[1]*

Entonces en el **controlador** hago una petición a mi DB y en *then* hago siguiente:

```
.then(function(data) {

    var dat = data.data;
    $scope.tickets = [];


    $scope.verificarCheckbox = function() {

        if ($scope.checkstate) {

            for (var i = 0; i < dat.length; i++) {
                dat[i]
                var ticket = {
                    numero: dat[i].numero,
                    rut: dat[i].rut,
                    servicio_id: LoginData.getData().id_servicio.split(",")[0]
                };
                $scope.tickets.push(ticket);
            }
        } else {

            for (var i = 0; i < dat.length; i++) {
                dat[i]
                var ticket = {
                    numero: dat[i].numero,
                    rut: dat[i].rut,
                    servicio_id: LoginData.getData().id_servicio.split(",")[1]
                };
                $scope.tickets.push(ticket);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

la idea es que si selecciono el checkbox mande el arreglo[0] y si lo de-selecciono que mande el arreglo [1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ocupar el evento `ng-change`

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="checkstate" ng-change="verificarCheckbox()" aria-label="Checkbox 1" ng-true-value="'prioritario'" ng-false-value="'Normal'">
    {{checknull}}
</md-checkbox>
```

Y desde tu controlador

```
$scope.verificarCheckbox = function(){
    if($scope.checkstate){
       //mande el arreglo[0]
    }else{
       //mande el arreglo[1]
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Ademas de agregar mi respuesta te aconsejo mejorar tu codigo, tienes dos bloques identiticos salvo por 1 valor que es tu valor del arreglo que depende del `checkbox` podrias hacer lo siguiente

```
.then(function(data) {

    var dat = data.data;
    $scope.tickets = [];


    $scope.verificarCheckbox = function() {
        var servicio_id = LoginData.getData().id_servicio.split(",")[0];
        if (!$scope.checkstate) {
            servicio_id = LoginData.getData().id_servicio.split(",")[1];
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < dat.length; i++) {
            dat[i]
            var ticket = {
                numero: dat[i].numero,
                rut: dat[i].rut,
                servicio_id: servicio_id
            };
            $scope.tickets.push(ticket);
        }
    }
});
```

Con esto le entregamos un valor a una variable llamada `servicio_id` que por defecto es el `[0]`, verificamos si el checkbox esta o no seleccionado. Si NO lo esta, asignamos el valor `[1]`.

Comment: el ng-model lo cambio por verificarCheckbox... ?

Comment: No @HernanHumaña, debes dejar el ng-model ya que con esto puedes acceder al valor desde el controlador, tienes que agregar el tag ng-change! que te permite llamar a una funcion cada vez que el valor de tu ng-model cambie

Comment: mira no me muestra correctamente... dejare el codigo en la pregunta

Comment: que es lo que no funciona?

Comment: supuestamente al asignarle el valor almacenado en el arreglo [0] o [1] debe mostrarme todos los rut y numeros que tienen el valor asignado, pero el autocompletar se marea

Comment: y no deberia porque solo muestra los datos que yo asigno con el checkbox, el cambio esta ahí

Comment: no entiendo muy bien a que te refieres, tu estas buscando que al cambiar el checkbox de valor, se agreguen distintos valores a un arreglo.... y eso es lo que hace el codigo no entiendo "se marea"

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47897/discussion-between-sioesi-and-hernan-humana).